# How to set a value in JSP session using javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

Is it possible to set/assign value in session using java script?

Basically, I have few links on my JSP page and on click of those links, I need to set a variable in session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

session is server side concept, while javascript plays on browser

- You can either use ajax on click of those link make a request to server and pass the info. and set it to session @ server

Or

- If those links on whichuser is going to click is your server's then pass some param with it. and track it at server

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to use a hidden input element bound to a bean property in session scope, and put a JavaScript onclick handler in a commandlink that sets the hidden element's value before submitting the page.

Comment: OP didn't mention anywhere that he is using JSF, so a JSF targeted answer might be confusing to him.

Comment: how do I bind a hidden input element to a bean property in a session scope. We are using struts 2.